# Understanding different methods of standardization

Tags: r, standardization

I am currently working on a scatterplot with two standardized values. One axis is compromised of the mean value of several differences between traits, a index so to say.

Index = ((A/B) + (C/D)) / 2

Since the traits are scored differently, I want to standardize them. Now I have the feeling I am confusing myself how to do that. Below an example:

```
A <- c(91.6, 57.7, 72.3, 63.2, 9.0, 31.3, 95.2, 28.4)
B <-c(0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.9)
C <-c(628.1, 710.6, 400.6, 710.5, 631.0, 538.5, 274.0, 981.5)
D <- c(3.5, 2.0, 3.7, 3.8, 2.5, 4.4, 5.6, 5.7)
data <- data.frame(A, B, C, D)

data$AB <- scale(data$A / data$B)
data$CD <- scale(data$C / data$D)
data.scale <- data
```

In this first method, I standardized each column showing the differences between A/B and C/D separately.

```
data <- data.frame(A, B, C, D)
data.mutate <- data %>% mutate_at(c(1:4), ~(scale(.) %>% as.vector))
data.mutate$AB <- data.stat$A / data.stat$B
data.mutate$CD <- data.stat$C / data.stat$D
```

In the second method, I standardized the whole data frame first before dividing them.
Of course, now I have different results.
Now I am looking for some input on how to do this because at this point I have completely confused myself.
More specific which "method" makes more "sense", or how much this is dependent on the research question itself. Hopefully, I didn't completely miss the point of standardization here.

Thank you for your input!

Comment: My instinct says that if your are primarily interested in A/B and C/D, then standardizing those quantities makes more sense then standardizing the inputs, but without context of your research question, your methods, why you are standardizing at all, etc., this is really just a shot in the dark.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for your input. Sorry, I forgot to change the site. I want to standardize them to get them on a similar scale. They are plant traits and the range from each trait can be very different.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a "correct" answer to your question. It depends on what you would like to do. First, there are a number of reasons to standardize, including:

- Putting variables on a similar scale for analysis. For example, if one variable is in small integers (e.g. 1 - 10) and another is in millions or billions, trying to put these both into a model can sometimes lead to the variable on the smaller scale having a muted effect.
- Standardizing interpretation. If all variables are on the same/ similar scale, you can interpret effect sizes in a similar manner (frequently in standard deviations).

So ask yourself: what am I trying to accomplish by standardizing? I think most likely your method of taking the ratio *before* standardizing is correct. The reasoning being that standardization is generally going to change the shape of the univariate distribution of your data, at least slightly. So, if you standardize all variables *first*, then you are going to get different ratios when dividing. I can't imagine any reason you would want to do this, as it really hampers any interpretability of your ratios.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. My reason is that I need to put the variables on a similar scale. I will think about your explanations, but it sounds very reasonable.

Comment: I think you should remove your third bullet - standardization by its common definition and as OP is applying it with the `scale` function is a linear transformation which will have no effect on normality. You need a nonlinear transformation for that.

Comment: Fair point. Removed.